# How can I get the FK:PK relationships from a Sqlite DB?

Tags: c#, sqlite, ado.net

How can I get the foreign key - primary key relationships from a Sqlite DB? I'm pulling down the table, view, & column metadata. But I can't find a way to get the relationships.

I am using C# and the System.Data.Sqlite ADO.NET connector.

thanks - dave

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is:

DataTable dt = cnn.GetSchema("foreignkeys", new [] {null, null, "table_name", null});

If you want to get it table by table.